# Duplicate code in spring controllers

Tags: java, spring

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> resetPassword(@RequestBody String email) {
    // Create password token and send by email, if email doesn't exist, don't send it
    Optional<AppUser> optionalUser = appUserService.findByEmail(email);
    if (optionalUser.isEmpty()) {
        throw new VerificationTokenException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Email not found");
    }

    AppUser user = optionalUser.get();
    if (user.isEnabled()) {
        throw new VerificationTokenException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "Something went wrong");
    }

    Optional<VerificationToken> optionalVerificationToken = verificationTokenService.findByUser(user);
    if (optionalVerificationToken.isPresent()) {
        VerificationToken verificationToken = optionalVerificationToken.get();
        verificationTokenService.delete(verificationToken);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

These 3 if staments are used in multiple methods in my Controller, what is a proper way to make them reusable?

I could extract each if statement into an individuel method like so, but on what level should I put them in? Should I create an util class
or keep them inside my Controller class which uses them?

```
private Optional<AppUser> getAppUser(String email) {
    Optional<AppUser> optionalUser = appUserService.findByEmail(email);
    if (optionalUser.isEmpty()) {
        throw new VerificationTokenException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Email not found");
    }
    return optionalUser;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extract those first 2 if's into separate methods (or single method), returning the user at the same time.
Something like `getDisabledUserOrThrow()` (Returning the `AppUser` instance, not `Optional`, because either you return a "valid" user (no-enabled) or throw your exception).

You can use that anywhere you need to ensure you have user instance. Something like this:

```
private AppUser getDisabledUserOrThrow(String email) throws VerificationTokenException {
    Optional<AppUser> optionalUser = appUserService.findByEmail(email);
    if (optionalUser.isEmpty()) {
        throw new VerificationTokenException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Email not found");
    }

    AppUser user = optionalUser.get();
    if (user.isEnabled()) {
        throw new VerificationTokenException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "Something went wrong");
    }
    return user;
}
```

You could do the same to get the token if that's what is the most common data necessary for your logic further.

Edit:

To expand on positioning this method:

- One way would be to put it in your parent controller (if you have one) as protected methods so that you can call them directly from your controller.
- I am also thinking - if those methods are basically getting your domain models, you can look at those as methods of Repositories (look up this pattern if needed) and inject them into your controllers :-)
- It's always possible to create static methods instead, which is also fine if there's no clear place of putting it.

Comment: Should i put it into a new class?

Comment: Honestly I can't answer that without knowing more context. One way would be to put it as protected into ancestor of this class or create a static function (and add parameter of type `appUserService`).

Comment: I expanded on this part of the answer a bit.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point out that you are using `Optional` badly. Generally the use of `isPresent`/`isEmpty` and `get` are an anti-pattern. Instead in this case you should be using `orElseThrow` and `ifPresent`, for example like this:

```
AppUser user = appUserService.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(
    () -> new VerificationTokenException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Email not found")
);

if (user.isEnabled()) {
    throw new VerificationTokenException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "Something went wrong");
}

verificationTokenService.findByUser(user).ifPresent(verificationTokenService::delete);
```